# ssh over python subprocess return two return code. One from the command and other is ssh error-255

Tags: python-2.7

The problem is when the cmd execution complete, I'm getting utilExit codes(pass,fail) but sometime getting 255 code(ssh failure). I don't why and the because of that first either fail loop or pass loop will print and then getting into ssh error(255) loop..anyone please help why two return code from the subprocess. and how to handle this.

```
#cmd: it is command which executed over the ssh on remote system
#FailExitCode : list of exit code of cmd which are considering for failure
#PassExitCode : list of exit code of cmd which are considering for pass
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
out,err = p.communicate()
utilExit = p.returncode
if utilExit in FailExitCode:
    logger.error("Utility has failed with Exit Code "+str(utilExit))
    status = "Failed"
    retCode = 1
    return retCode,status

elif utilExit in PassExitCode:
     logger.info("Utility has completed execution successfully with exit code :" + str(utilExit))
     status = "Passed"
     retCode = 0
     return retCode,status

elif (utilExit == 255):
     logger.info("Due to the SSH Error, will re-execute after 60 seconds " + err)
     time.sleep(60)
     code,status = self.Execute(cmd, ip, type)
     return code,status
```

Comment: Its cmd that is failing... what is it?

Comment: @tdelaney: cmd pass or fail it return the code accordingly but I'm getting ssh error 255 as well along with the cmd return code

Comment: @tdelaney: suppose cmd has given return code pass. so it is executing {elif utilExit in PassExitCode :} but along with this,  {elif (utilExit == 255):} is also executing. Also I've given return statement in the {elif utilExit in PassExitCode :} loop. So why it is executing another elif loop {elif (utilExit == 255):}

Comment: Unless you've got an indentation error not seen here (this is in a function you don't show so maybe...) only 1 of those 3 blocks will execute. If its not in `FailExitCode` (assuming a list of integer exit codes) and is in `PassExitCode`, just the "Utility has completed..." log should be seen. You could log the subprocess call itself to see if you are calling this function again, getting a different code, and seeing two logs.

Comment: code is running fine no indentation error. function : sub process has started execution and got the return code. logging exit code :2 is from the cmd which is passed and after that immediately getting 255. For workaroung I have added re-execute the function again if ssh error 255 occurs. But ideally it should not give two return code as we got the cmd exit code:2.           
**Output**  is :
[INFO]
[INFO] Utility has completed execution successfully with exit code :2
[INFO] Due to the SSH Error, will re-execute after 60 seconds Connection to *IP* closed by remote host.